# BLoC State Management pattern (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

Google suggests the use of the **BLoC pattern** to manage the state of a Flutter app. I have read that together with `rxdart`, it is the most convenient and complete way to manage the state. So, I would like to understand and learn that pattern.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no complete and *exhaustive* documentation. Can somebody explain to me clearly this pattern and its implementation in a Flutter app?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to see this url https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/

Comment: @SantoshAnand, thank you very much! I’m sorry but I had read it yet, and I did not find it very clear. I’m searching a comprehensive explication. The solution I’m searching is the most _pure_ posible using `Stream`s and `rxdart`. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some helpful links. 
Those are explanations with examples made by Didier Boelens :

The basics with streams and BLoC pattern ([Reactive Programming - Streams - BLoC](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/))

A bit deeper and practical exemple ([Reactive Programming - Streams - BLoC - Practical Use Cases](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/12/reactive-programming---streams---bloc---practical-use-cases/))

A comparison between BLoC, ScopedModel and Redux ([BLoC - ScopedModel - Redux - Comparison](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/04/bloc---scopedmodel---redux---comparison/))

It helped me a lot and I hope you will find what you want too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested in this topic I would recommend flutter_bloc library and its [official documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted). It makes working with this pattern a real pleasure. If you will be looking for more practical usage of this library I have recently written a [blog post](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article - [Bloc pattern for Flutter on the classic counter example](https://medium.com/@alexawaikin/bloc-pattern-for-flutter-on-the-classic-counter-example-d7af74df9a76).

There is clear explanation of BLoC and working example of "classic" counter app rewritten with BLoC pattern.

[image]

Comment: I found it useful. Thanks!